# Read data from .net files in MATLAB

Tags: .net, matlab, file-io, import

I have a large amount of data that is stored in multiple .net files and I wanted to process them using MATLAB (my current version is R2013a). Despite searching the MathWorks website, I was unable to find any command for importing data from .net files since the `ncread` command works only for .nc files. An image of the structure of the file(s), after opening with Notepad++, can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ww5P.jpg).

As can be seen, the file has the data separated by `NUL US NUL` and starts with `US NUL`, the Unit Separator and Null characters. I was looking for a method to read in the file such that each of the three entries between the `NUL US NUL` characters corresponds to the three columns of one row.

One option would be for me to manually open each file with Notepad++ and replace `\x00\x1f\x00` with `\n`, then open the file with Microsoft Excel, delimited by spaces, and save it as a .csv file, which I can in turn import into MATLAB with the `csvread` command. However, since I have nearly 600 .net files, this does not seem to be a practical solution, simply because of scale of the effort required. I would be really grateful if someone could help me out in this regard and suggest an efficient method to read these files into MATLAB. Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you please post some of the actual data somewhere so we can try solutions? Thanks!

Comment: @darthbith I am really very sorry but I am not at liberty to post the data or any representative sample thereof online. Hence, I could only show you the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
function mat=filetrim(filename,'NUL US NUL') % 
tic
fid=fopen(filename);
if (isunix) % Linux or Mac
    [~, result] = system( ['wc -l ', filename] );
    nl=strcat(regexp(result,'[\d]','match'));
    numlines = str2double(nl);

elseif (ispc) % Windows
    numlines = str2double( perl('countlines.pl', 'your_file') );

else
    error('...');

end
tline=fgetl(fid);
r=regexp(strtrim(tline(7:end-6)),pat,'split');% here I assumed that the line ends with
                                              % US NUL. If the line does not end with
                                              % US NUL, please change the "end-6" to
                                              % "end".
d=cell2mat(cellfun(@str2num,r,'UniformOutput',false));
mat=zeros(numlines,size(d,2));
for i=1:size(mat,1)
    r=regexp(strtrim(tline(7:end-6)),pat,'split');
    mat(i,:)=cell2mat(cellfun(@str2num,r,'UniformOutput',false));
end
fclose all;
toc
return
```

**The loop to find out the number of lines in the file was adapted from one of the solutions provided in the "Stackoverflow". The credit goes to @Rody Oldenhuis for this part.**

Comment: Thanks for your help but there seems to be an issue with your code. The following is the error message I receive when I try to execute it: `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.`
`Error in filetrim (line 17)`
`mat(i,:)=cell2mat(cellfun(@str2num,r,'UniformOutput',false));`
Could you please check this out? Thanks!

Comment: please send me the file you are working on. I have tried with a sample file and it worked. My mail id is naveen.bhatraju@igib.in

Comment: @UserXeTex, I saw your earlier comment just now and learnt that You can not send the data file. Do one thing, Just copy the first row and last row of the input file into another text file and send me.

Answer (score 0):

Functions to consider:

- fgetl
- dlmread
- textscan
- NC toolbox for reading several standard file formats. http://code.google.com/p/nctoolbox/